# Line break with _

Tags: line-breaking, typography

I have been searching what is the proper line break when using `_` but I did not find any rules for that. I have a table which is too big and the content has to be divided into two lines.

I have a name (`blabla_rest`) that contains an `_`. What is the correct way to break it?

1. blabla_(new line)rest
2. blabla(new line)_rest
3. blabla_(new line)_rest

Comment: This is heavily context-dependent: It looks like a identifier from a programming language, in which case you should use the line continuation character from that language (and may look at the [listings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) package.  In most cases though, if used in running text (as opposed to a whole listing), I would try to avoid breaking in the middle of an identifier.  The best option is probably to leave the "_" trailing at the end of the line - and duplicating it is highly unlikely to be best.

Comment: I'd use 1 or in some contexts consider _ as a letter and hyphenate: blabla_-(new line)rest which looks a bit odd but is perhaps the most explicit that the word is broken

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Could you make an example to play with?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 4):

use the `ngerman` shorthands, then you can use `""` to define a break point without a hyphen:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}

\begin{document}

I have a name (blabla\_rest) that contains \_ sign. What is the correct way to break it?
blabla\_""(new line)rest

\begin{minipage}{4cm}
bla bla bla bla bla blabla\_""(new line)rest
and some other nonsense text
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could make the `_` character active and define it to be `\textunderscore` in text mode, with a possible line break point after it, while keeping it to be the subscript character in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`_
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \protected\def~{%
    \ifmmode
      \sb
    \else
      \nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}% allow hyphenating before the underscore
      \textunderscore\penalty\exhyphenpenalty % just like \slash
      \hspace{0pt}% allow hyphenating after the underscore
    \fi
  }
}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=\active}

\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}%
something_something
}

\bigskip

$a_1$
\end{document}
```

The `\parbox` is just to force breaking as much as possible.

[image]